# How do I update Podio item using PUT and JSON?

Tags: json, put, podio

I'm try to update a item in podio, but it shows object not found.

my code

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api.podio.com/item/53",
  "method": "PUT",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer "+token+""
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({"external_id":"site survey","fields":[{"field_id":217397820,"type":"email","values":[{"type":"work","value":"tets@gmail.com"}]}]}),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Provide exact `item_id` here `https://api.podio.com/item/{item_id}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `app_item_id` instead of the `item_id`. The `app_item_id` is specific to the app and is shorter. The `item_id` will be long.